# Updating ListView from multiple background Tasks keeps adding the same ListViewItem

Tags: c#, .net, listview, task

The code below iterates through a List collection. The Server object simply contains a description and URL property and is populated at the start of program execution.

For each Server in `List<Server>` I start a new task that calls a function called `GetMonitorData`. `GetMonitorData` simply reads the remote file in, parses out some data, and returns a `ListViewItem` containing the parsed out data. Finally, after the task finishes I add the returned `ListViewItem` to the `ListView` in `ContinueWith()`:

```
foreach (Server server in Servers)
{
    Task<ListViewItem> mainTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<ListViewItem>(() =>
    {
        return GetMonitorData(server);
    });

    Task contTask = mainTask.ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        lstServers.Items.Add(task.Result);
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
}

private ListViewItem GetMonitorData(Server server)
{
    XDocument monitorDoc = XDocument.Load(server.MonitorURL);
    string version = monitorDoc.Root.Element("version").Value;
    ListViewItem lstItem = new ListViewItem(new string[] { server.ClientName, version });
    return lstItem;
}

public class Server
{
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string MonitorURL { get; set; }
}
```

For some reason though I just keep getting the same `ListViewItem` back in `ContinueWith()`, so my ListView has multiple copies of the same `ListViewItem` in it. Interestingly, if I uncomment the `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)` line (thereby giving the task a little time to finish) I get a unique `ListViewItem` for each Server in `List<Server>` as expected.

What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps `GetMonitorData()` is not thread-safe. Can you post the code for `GetMonitorData`?

Comment: Is you `GetMonitorData` method thread-safe?

Comment: try to [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) `GetMonitorData()`.
anyway, no one will be able to help you if don't show more code

Comment: If he uses a `lock`, there is no point in spinning up those tasks at all, as they'll all be waiting on it and actually executing sequentially.

Comment: Shoot, never even knew there were replies or I would have replied sooner. I added the GetMonitorData() function. The function finishes pretty quickly at this point since it really just gets an XML file but it will eventually grow which is why I'm starting with unique threads right off the bat. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works! Before creating the task I assign the parameter I pass to GetMonitorData() to a temporary variable first. See modified code below:

```
foreach (Server server in Servers)
{
    Server tmpServer = server;
    Task<ListViewItem> mainTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<ListViewItem>(() =>
    {
        return GetMonitorData(tmpServer);
    });

    Task contTask = mainTask.ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        lstServers.Items.Add(task.Result);
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

I didn't figure this out on my own though, [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/5074fe3c-9ada-441d-8586-ea9ff4362830/taskfactorystartnew-messing-up-parameters) provided the vital clue.